# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que un campo tipo choice se sobre ponga a otros campos?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Mi objetivo es agregar varios campos en un modelo, incluyendo tipo choise. Sin embargo, solo me aparece un campo, que es el tipo choice.

[image: Campo tipo choice]

He intentado poner sexo_cliente (las tuplas con las opciones) al final de la clase model, pero me notificaba que sexo_cliente  no existía. Puse sexo_cliente  dentro de la clase model, pero igual. No sé si directamente no se puede combinar varios tipos de campos, o si hago algo mal. Ayudaaaa :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En realidad lo que te falta sería otro Choise, en la cual escoges las duplas y luego recien otro choise donde puedas escoger los datos dentro de las duplas

Comment: Hola!
¿Entonces creo otro campo para opciones dentro de sexo_cliente, que escoja las tuplas?